# How to solve PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, debugging

Hello so I am getting this error permission denied when I run this python script.

```
import os

keyword = input("Enter Keyword to search : ")
replacement = input("Enter replacement string : ")

for filename in os.listdir():
   with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), 'r') as f: # open in readonly mode
       content = f.read()
       if keyword in content:
           with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), 'w') as fw: # open in write mode
               writecontent = content.replace(keyword, replacement)
               fw.write(writecontent)
               print(f"Keyword {keyword} found and replaced in file : {filename}")


input("Press Enter to exit")
```

the error I am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/smraf/Desktop/Test Python/script.py", line 9, in <module>
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), 'r') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Test Python\\.vscode'
```

The problem is when I run this on a different laptop it works. My coworker tried running it on theirs and it doesn't work either so I am not sure why it's giving me this error.

Comment: Try running as an admin

Comment: It seems to me you are writing to a file you still have open for reading. Move `if keyword in content` outside the scope of the first `with` clause.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are attempting to open a directory (in this case, `.vscode`) as if it were a file.  You can't do this, and on Windows you will get a permission-denied error if you try.  Running your script as administrator will make no difference.

What should your script do when it encounters a directory?  Ignore it altogether, or recursively process the files within the directory?

If you just need to ignore directories, call [`os.path.isfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) with the filename you get from `os.listdir()`, and if `os.path.isfile` returns `False`, skip that filename.  If however you need to recursively process files, look at [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) instead.