# errno 13: permission denied in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, permission-denied

[ VSCODE ]  it's a simple code to read a text file, but it keeps giving me errno 13

```
with open('movie.txt') as file_object:
    content = file_object.read()
    print(content.strip())
```

the file is saved as movie.txt, but when i used that it said there was no file under that name, when I do in fact have it saved. when i changed changed to with open('movie'), without the .txt extension, it said permission error. I've searched everywhere but i cant find the solution.

UPDATE : works if i use absolute path.

Comment: where the hell is .txt extention of that file ?

Comment: Hello - Welcome. Because of the vaguness of question I am going to assume you need to run vscode as admin if you are in windows. Permission error is usually permissions (as it sounds) or the file is currently locked/inuse.

Comment: You probably have a directory called *movie* in your current working directory. If you want to open movie.txt try using an absolute path

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As you can see from the comments, the question is not really clear. Please read [ask] and try to improve your question so it's more on-topic here.

Comment: So it seemed like you had a simple path error which has now been solved. Is there still a question? Otherwise you might remove this question, since it does not seem to be useful for others, IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68169558/18359438). There is a directory named `movie` in your directory structure, which makes vscode open a directory instead of a file.

What you need to do is replace `movie` with `movie.txt`:

```
with open("movie.txt") as file_object:
    content = file_object.read()
    print(content.strip())
```